# Keras data augmentation with change in outputs

Tags: python-3.x, keras, data-augmentation

I want to do regression with images. There are images of roads and the associated steering angle. As I want to apply [data augmentation in Keras](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) I would like to flip the input images horizontally but that would imply that the steering angle has to change its sign if the image is flipped. As far as I can see the documentation does not cover this problem. Is there a tutorial explaining how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own data-generator. 
Check out the **ImageLoader** class (custom image generator) in my code here:

https://github.com/Golbstein/EDSR-Keras/blob/master/utilities.py

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will wait if someone will come up with a out of the box solution. If there is no other answer I will accept your answer.

Comment: the out of the box answer is to create your own generator. There's no way to augment the labels with keras's generator